# Mysql date_sub interval 12 month

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all posts from the 12 last month, group by month. I have a quite correct query:

```
SELECT MONTH(time) as mois, YEAR(time) as annee, count(*) as nbre
FROM touist_stories
WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(now() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
group by MONTH(time)
order by YEAR(time) DESC, MONTH(time) DESC
```

But one month is always missing : november 2012
I tryied to add

```
+ INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

to now() but it still missing... How can I get the 12 last month and not the 11 ones please?
Thanks

Comment: do you have records for November ?

Comment: There's always 12 months in a year right?

Comment: No, november is always missing! And there is always 11 month instead of 12

Answer (score 0):

To get one year ago, here's a technique I've used in the past.  Using @mysql variables, create a date based on the first day of a given month/year (via now()), then subtract 12 months.  This example will get from Oct 1, 2012 to current -- which will include current Oct 2013.  To exclude that, just add to where clause where I re-added 1 year so it goes from Oct 1, 2012 at 12:00:00 am to LESS THEN Oct 1, 2013 12:00:00.

```
SELECT 
      MONTH(time) as mois, 
      YEAR(time) as annee, 
      count(*) as nbre
   FROM 
      touist_stories,
      ( select @lastYear := date_add( DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),
         '%Y-%m-01'), interval -11 month) ) sqlvar
   WHERE 
      time >= @lastYear
   group by 
      MONTH(time)
   order by 
      YEAR(time) DESC, 
      MONTH(time) DESC
```

Revised to make it go 11 months back (to November per example), and include UP TO AND INCLUDING all Current October activity.

Comment: Quite good, but always the current month missing... How to have from november 2012 to october 2013?

Comment: @user2670167, or could have just done interval -11 month :)  Since you want CURRENT October to be included, remove the  AND time < date_add portion so all of current October is included too.

Answer (score 0):

For realy want on year data use 11 MONTH not 12

```
SELECT time
FROM touist_stories
WHERE time 
BETWEEN 
 date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH)
AND 
 Now();
```